# SAS PROC SQL - %Sales by Customer/State

Tags: sas

I seem unable to attach an excel file with the formula I need to replicate in PROC SQL. Essentially create a percent of sales by customer/state (all states for one customer add up to 100%) that can then be applied to other variables that do not exist at state level so to approximate state level metrics for those other variables.

This is part of SAS code that is joining 9 data sources and needs to be in PROC SQL.

The excel formula is at customer/state level: (sales/sumif(account=account,sales)) * non-state variable

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what does the Excel function SIMIF() do?  What is SALES? What is ACCOUNT?  Why are you comparing ACCOUNT to ACCOUNT, isn't that always going to be TRUE?

Comment: SUMIF is summing if conditions are met, in this case the condition is when account numbers are the same. it's summing sales  if the account numbers match. Sales/Total Sales by Account = %Sales by Acct - but in this case it's by Account & State. I need %Sales by Account and State.

Comment: Explanation does not make any sense, but in SQL if you want to sum conditionally then use a CASE clause inside SUM() aggregate function. Something like `sum(case when a.account=b.account then b.sales else 0 end)`